# Como funciona um servidor de jogo online?

Tags: python, python-3.x, servidor, dns

Isso é mais uma duvida sobre jogos online, recentemente estudei OpenGL e aprendi como funciona o processo de criação de videogames, estava interessado em aprender mais para criar um MMO, para isso comecei a pesquisar como funcionam servidores a fim de criar um para um jogo que eu desenvolver futuramente, minhas duvidas são:

- Como funciona o DNS? Eu sei que eu preciso de um nome de domínio para fazer as coisas funcionarem online mas gostaria de saber como eu manipularia as informações dele, eu sei `HTML`, `CSS`, `PHP` e `JavaScript`, eles poderiam funcionar em conjunto com um servidor para jogadores online? Ou seria necessário fazer uma programação, por exemplo em `python` onde o servidor se conectaria com o nome de domínio e ele receberia e mandaria informações por conta própria?
- Se eu quisesse otimizar a velocidade do servidor, informações passadas por um protocolo UDP seriam mais rápidas para comandos de gameplay enquanto informações como a autenticação de jogadores seria melhor usar TCP? Por que eu quero fazer meu servidor seguro, mas também quero entender como isso poderia funcionar para otimizar a velocidade do mesmo.
- Conhecem algum tipo de serviço online para terceirizar servidores de jogos que eu mesmo programar? Por que já vi online serviços para criar sites grátis e coloca-los online com um nome estranho, e até alguns servidores para jogos famosos, mas eu não me lembro de um feito para que eu mesmo programe internamente o servidor.

P.S.: Eu já criei sites antes e coloquei eles online, sei como funcionam domínios e hospedagem de sites, mas nunca coloquei um servidor para um jogo online, então podem explicar com detalhes, gosto de entender como tudo funciona, e de preferência em `Python` que é a principal linguagem de programação que eu uso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caramba você tá muito confuso e misturando tudo ...

`DNS(Domain name server)`- não tem nada haver com linguagem de programação, nada haver com HTML, PHP, Python, etc, o `DNS` é um serviço que converte um nome em `IP`, no servidor vc define um endereço de IP público e fixo, depois você diz no `DNS` que o seu site ex. www.exemplo.com.br possui o `IP` que está configurado na interface de rede do Servidor!

Protocolo UDP é muito usado em Streaming por não ser confiável, ao enviar um pacote por este protocolo não existe garantias e nem retransmissão, se o pacote não chegar no destino baubau lol, é super interessante para streaming de áudio e videos, em teoria no montante todo se um pacote ou outro falhar você ainda irá entender uma frase de áudio, claro o protocolo possuí alta eficiência por não ter controle algum dos pacotes enviados, parece ser interessante usar UDP para os comandos, e sim acho importante o uso do protocolo TCP para autenticações...

Sobre a ultima pergunta fica complicado de responder, seu jogo vai rodar em um browser ? se sim seu servidor terá que ter um servidor Web(apache, nginx, etc), e ai você só terá que se preocupar com a parte de desenvolvimento web.

Comment: Eu imaginei o jogo como um programa executável